# How to set cache size in ZODB?

Tags: python, zodb

I establish ZODB connection with the following code:

```
connection = ZODB.connection('zodb/connect4_reinf.fs')
dbroot = connection.root()
```

How can I set RAM cache size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code of class DB:

```
  def __init__(self, storage,
             pool_size=7,
             pool_timeout=1<<31,
             cache_size=400,
             cache_size_bytes=0,
             historical_pool_size=3,
             historical_cache_size=1000,
             historical_cache_size_bytes=0,
             historical_timeout=300,
             database_name='unnamed',
             databases=None,
             xrefs=True,
             large_record_size=1<<24,
             **storage_args):
```

When `ZODB.connection` is defined as follows:

```
def connection(*args, **kw):
    return DB(*args, **kw).open_then_close_db_when_connection_closes()
```

I would say

```
   connection = ZODB.connection('zodb/connect4_reinf.fs',
        cache_size=<your-cache-size>)
```

Also there's a cache_size_bytes if you prefer the limit to be in (estimated) bytes. 0 means unlimited for this parameter.

Comment: I'm also intrested how `cache_size` and `cache_size_bytes` are connected.

Comment: Do you know why ZODB caches more objects than configured `cache_size`, while releasing them on `cacheMinimize()` call? It seems to me like the configuration for RAM cache size is being simply ignored by ZODB.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605884/zodb-ignores-target-cached-object-count-and-target-cache-memory-size
Thanks in advance — it would be of great help if you could point to anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the connection between cache_size and cache_size_bytes
(I'm posting this as an answer, since comments are a bit short for this purpose)

This time, we can find the answer in picklecache.py, again in the source code. After some renaming, it boils down to the following lines (in method _sweep):

```
for value in self.ring:
    if self.non_ghost_count <= target and (self.total_estimated_size <= target_size_bytes or not target_size_bytes):
            break
    (delete some objects from the cache)
```

here `target` is the `cache_size` of `connection`, in number of objects, and `target_size_bytes` is the `cache_size_bytes` passed to `connection`, in bytes. So in short, if `cache_size_bytes` evals to `False` (as the default value `0`, but also `None`, etc...), only the number of objects is taken into account. If `cache_size_bytes` is present, both `cache_size` and `cache_size_bytes` are taken into account, and both conditions must apply, that is when an object must be brought into the cache, if the addition will lead to have more than `cache_size` living objects *or* more than `cache_size_bytes` bytes (estimated), some object will be deleted from the cache to make more room available.