# ZODB ignores target cached object count and target cache memory size

Tags: python, caching, zodb

I want to use ZODB with as little caching as possible. For this, I'm creating ZODB database instance and opening it like this:

```
db = DB('/home/me/example.db', cache_size=1, cache_size_bytes=1)
db_conn = db.open_then_close_db_when_connection_closes()
```

`db_conn` is the only connection of `db`. I'm verifying that both its target cache size parameters are set by checking `db_conn._cache.cache_size` and `db_conn._cache.cache_size_bytes`, which evaluate to `1` each.

In the database, I store lots (could be billions and more) of Persistent objects in one OOBTree. When I'm reading them (in batches) from the database, my memory usage grows. Calling `db_conn.cacheMinimize()` after each (batch) read prevents memory usage from growing, but *I want ZODB not to cache the objects in the first place* (as opposed to me forcing it to remove cached objects from memory).

I am monitoring database cache status right before and right after each `cacheMinimize()` call using `cacheDetail()` and `cacheDetailSize()` like this:

```
cache_status_before = {'detail': db_conn.db().cacheDetail(),
                       'detail size': db_conn.db().cacheDetailSize()}
db_conn.cacheMinimize()
cache_status_after = {'detail': db_conn.db().cacheDetail(),
                      'detail size': db_conn.db().cacheDetailSize()}
print('{} -> {}'.format(cache_status_before, cache_status_after))
```

A typical output produced by the above lines is (Simulation is the class of my objects, inherited from Persistent):

```
{'detail': [('BTrees.OOBTree.OOBucket', 62), ('boolsi.simulate.Simulation', 1758)],
'detail size': [{'connection': '<Connection at 7fe9340966a0>', 'ngsize': 933, 'size': 1820}]}
->
{'detail': [('BTrees.OOBTree.OOBucket', 3), ('boolsi.simulate.Simulation', 1748)],
'detail size': [{'connection': '<Connection at 7fe9340966a0>', 'ngsize': 0, 'size': 1751}]}
```

From my understanding, **this output shows that both target cached object count and target cache memory size are ignored by ZODB**, since it caches more than 1 object (and definitely exceeding 1 byte). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZODB's cache and object tree are the same thing.  When you retrieve objects, they **live** in the cache.  If ZODB enforced cache size continuously, you wouldn't be able to load objects with your settings.

If you want ZODB to remove objects from the cache more often, consider committing transactions more frequently.  Note that if you're loading objects from a BTree in batches, you want some objects to be cached so you don't have to reload intermediate objects over and over.

Comment: I would only add for the sake of comprehensiveness that target cache size is enforced at transaction boundaries, and not all the time.

Comment: Relevant thread from ZODB Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zodb/cExsoJ7OkvI